Generic enum function call
I have an enum named Partitioning. I want each member of Partitioning to have its own partitioning algorithm. For example, the following would invoke the partitioning algorithm for BLAH:
Partitioning.BLAH.partition(myData, value);

The problem is that the objects I am manipulating all use generics, and I cannot get the generics to work correctly.
These are the classes involved.
public class MyData<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<MyData<T>> {
    public List<MyData<T>> partition(T value, Partitioning partitioning) {
        return partitioning.partition(this, value);
    }

    private interface PartitioningAlgorithm<U extends Comparable<? super U>>  {
        List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value);
    }

    private static class MyAlgorithm<U extends Comparable<? super U>> implements PartitioningAlgorithm<U> {
        public MyAlgorithm() {
            // Nothing to do
        }
        @Override
        public List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
            return null; // TODO: Stubbed out for now
        }
    }

    public enum Partitioning {
        BLAH(new MyAlgorithm());

        private final PartitioningAlgorithm<? extends Comparable<?>> algorithm;

        <U extends Comparable<? super U>> Partitioning(PartitioningAlgorithm<U> algorithm) {
            this.algorithm = algorithm;
        }

        private <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
            return algorithm.partition(myData, value);
        }
    }
}


In the enum's partition method definition, for the line:
return algorithm.partition(myData, value);

I get the following compile error:
java: incompatible types: MyData<U> cannot be converted to MyData<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Comparable<?>>

I assume that value will give a similar error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If all the partitioning algorithms associated with each enum constant is a "general" partitioning algorithm that can partition every type of object, PartioningAlgorithm should not be generic. Instead, make its partition method generic.
private interface PartitioningAlgorithm  {
    <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value);
}

private static class MyAlgorithm implements PartitioningAlgorithm {
    public MyAlgorithm() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    @Override
    public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
        return null; // TODO: Stubbed out for now
    }
}

public enum Partitioning {
    BLAH(new MyAlgorithm());

    private final PartitioningAlgorithm algorithm;

    Partitioning(PartitioningAlgorithm algorithm) {
        this.algorithm = algorithm;
    }

    private <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
        return algorithm.partition(myData, value);
    }
}

If some partitioning algorithms can only partition a specific type of object, then this design is inherently not type-safe. The best you can do is to throw an exception at runtime when a partitioning algorithm is used to partition something that it cannot partition.
Add a canPartition method to PartitioningAlgorithm:
private interface PartitioningAlgorithm  {
    <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value);
    
    boolean canPartition(Class<?> type);
}

private static class MyAlgorithm implements PartitioningAlgorithm {
    public MyAlgorithm() {
        // Nothing to do
    }
    @Override
    public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
        return null; // TODO: Stubbed out for now
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPartition(Class<?> type) {
        return true; // can partition everything
    }
}

Here is an example of an implementation that only partitions strings:
private static class OnlyPartitionStrings implements PartitioningAlgorithm {
    @Override
    public <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
        return null; // TODO: Stubbed out for now
        // here ytou should cast to String whenever needed
    }

    @Override
    public boolean canPartition(Class<?> type) {
        return String.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }
}

In the enum, you would first check canPartition and potentially throw an exception.
private <U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<MyData<U>> partition(MyData<U> myData, U value) {
    if (algorithm.canPartition(value.getClass())) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException(algorithm + " cannot partition " + value.getClass());
    }
    return algorithm.partition(myData, value);
}


Mine is the first case: "all the partitioning algorithms associated with each enum constant is a 'general' partitioning algorithm that can partition every type of object."
You suggestions worked perfectly! Thank you!

Sorry, @Sweeper. I am new and did not know to do this. I have accepted. Thank you again!
